# Decipher a unix executable file

Tags: unix

There is a unix executable file and I want to read the contents of that file. It is in an unreadable format and needs to be deciphered. It does not have any extension, when I do a cat of it on the terminal its in an unreadable format.

Is there any command that I can use to decipher it or any tool that can help. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If it's unreadable with `cat` then it's probably an executable format such as `a.out` or, more likely, `ELF` (though it *could* be a different format).

If your executable is `xyzzy`, you should be able to find out what type it is by using `file xyzzy` on it, such as with:

```
pax> file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386,
         version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
         (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18,
         stripped
```

That file format is well documented (such as starting from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) if you search the web, and there are tools like `gcb`, `nm`, `readelf` and `objdump` which can look inside it to varying degrees, but all it's likely to deliver to you is the raw assembly language. Getting back to easily-understandable source code will be very hard.

Comment: I just go to know the extension of the file. It is .pc i think that is Pro C file... any suggestions how can I read this.. I am using a Mac system.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to decipher it (unless it has some binary-level obfuscation because it's an IOCCC entry). You can disassemble it using `otool -tv` or `objdump` and read what the program inside does.)

Comment: I just go to know the extension of the file. It is .pc i think that is Pro C file... any suggestions how can I read this.. I am using a Mac system

Comment: @Arunabh In your question, "It does not have any extension". Now what?